# How to convert the height of a div to 100% value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a `div` that I want to apply CSS transform [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()) property with a dynamic value based on the parent div's scroll position.

So say I have a `div` with an [id](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_id.asp) called `#circle` that has a parent `div` called `#main`. I want to find the `#main` div's height and divide it by 100 to create a dynamic value. Using this dynamic value, I want to animate the `#circle` `div` on [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event). So when the user is at the top of the `#main` `div`, the `#circle` is scaled at zero per cent, and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the `main` `div`, the circle has a scaling value of  100%.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nL5o1u3z/).

Comment: You should not do that, and likely Firefox will raise a warning related to scrolling. This will be slow and possibly freeze slow devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your scrolling container is actually the `html` element itself. So based on it's `scrollTop`,`scrollHeight` and the visible height i.e. `window.innerHeight`, we can calculate the `circleScale` value. All that part is handled inside `scrollLogic()` function.

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
const html = document.documentElement;
document.body.onscroll = () => {
  const circleScale = scrollLogic();
  circle.style.transform = `scale(${circleScale})`;
};

const scrollLogic = () => {
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const circleScale = Math.min(
    1,
    scrollFraction+0.1
  );
  return circleScale
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}



#main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spacing {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div id="circle"></div>
  <div class="spacing"></div>
</section>
```

**Edit** - For `main` to be a **scrolling-container**, it needs a certain fixed height so that the `spacing` of height `150vh` can cause the `main` of height `80vh` to overflow. Then the `scroll` event and calculations will happen on `main` itself. But also keep in mind that now since `main` itself is scrolling, the **perceived position** of the `circle` will also change and as it's scale increases, some of it will get cut down by the top of `main` container.

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
const html = document.documentElement;
const main = document.getElementById('main');
main.onscroll = () => {
  const circleScale = scrollLogic();
  circle.style.transform = `scale(${circleScale})`;
};

const scrollLogic = () => {
  const scrollTop = main.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = main.scrollHeight - main.offsetHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const circleScale = Math.min(
    1,
    scrollFraction+0.1
  );
  return circleScale
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}



#main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  height:80vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spacing {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div id="circle"></div>
  <div class="spacing"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, Lakshya Thakur. What if I want the scroll container to be the `#main` section?

Comment: @kayee I have added another snippet for `main` to be a scrolling container.

Comment: thanks for the example. It is not exactly what I am after but I can work with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offsetHeight` property to get the height of the element.

ex.
`document.getElementById("circle").offsetHeight`